# connecting outlets to a subclassed view controller

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I'm working through Paul Hegarty's course on iTunesU on developing iOS7 Apps. In assignment 3, I was required to make my view controller abstract and then make two concrete subclasses of it. The outlets in the original view controller were declared in the `.m` file as follows:

```
@interface CardGameViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIlabel *scorelabel;

@end
```

My problem is that my subclasses of `CardGameViewController` do not know about these properties  since, I presume, they are private.

In his hints for the assignment, Paul suggested an idea to get around this without making these outlet property declarations public:

> "If you subclass a subclass of UIViewController, you can wire up to
>   the superclass’s outlets and actions simply by manually opening up the
>   superclass’s code in the Assistant Editor in Xcode (side-by-side with
>   the storyboard) and ctrl-dragging to it as you normally would. In
>   other words, you are not required to make a superclass’s outlets and
>   actions public (by putting them in its header file) just to wire up to
>   them with ctrl-drag (it is quite possible to implement this entire
>   assignment without making a single outlet or action public)."

My question is: does this mean any code which uses these outlet properties must exist in the superclass implementation? Or is there a way for my subclass to access these properties?

Comment: Where is the connection of the IDE you are using (Xcode) to this question?

Comment: The outlet connections to the original view controller were made by control dragging from the UIView on a story board to the view controller .m file using Xcode.

Comment: I see your point, but i'm still not sure what Paul Hegarty means with the following hint either:"There is no concept like “protected” in Objective-C. Unfortunately, if a subclass wants to send messages to its superclass in code (not with ctrl-drag), those methods (including properties) will have to be made public. A good object-oriented design usually keeps publication of internal implementation to a minimum!"

Comment: In some languages there is a `protected` modifier that would mean that access would be limited to only subclasses. There is not way of restricting property access at all in Objective-C all you can do is change it's visibility. If a class can't see a property it can't use  it - hence putting it in the implementation is the closest you get to making it private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use the outlets in a subclass you would need to make them visible to the subclass in some way.

You can do this by making them publicly visible - place them in the header

or

You can make a new header that is to be imported by subclasses only (this is how `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses work)

```
@interface MyClass (ForSubclassEyesOnly)

@property (nonatomic, strong) id propertyThatYouWantToMakeVisibleToSubclass;

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. Since the course hasn't covered this yet, and since the assignment hint says not to make the outlets public, I believe code that uses these outlets must reside in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you are right.
He said: you are not required to make a superclass’s outlets and actions public (by putting them in its header file) just to wire up to them with ctrl-drag.

It means you don't need to make a superclass’s outlets and actions public, but it should be in the implementation file.

And in his tutorial, the scoreLabel property has already been in the CardGameViewController implementation file.